# How to prove that $\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ diverges as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits

Consider the limit
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$

How to show that this limit is $+\infty$? I just tried square criterion but it doesn’t work. Moreover, Stirling’s formula is not allowed (requested in the assignment).

Could anyone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps try find a similar, simpler sequence $a_n$ whose limit is $+\infty$, and then show that $$a_n\le \frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$ for each $n$ (or at least for each $n$ greater than some $N$)? Not tried it myself so don't know if it would prove fruitful but might be worth giving a go.

Comment: Did you try series expansion

Comment: Stirling approximations are not allowed?? Damn...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It holds that
\begin{align*}
\log n! & = \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\log k}  \le \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\log t \,\mathrm{d}t} } \\ & = \log n + \int_1^n {\log t\,\mathrm{d}t}  = \log n +n\log n - n,
\end{align*}
i.e.,
$$
n! \le n\left( {\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^n.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{{2^{\sqrt n } }}{n} \le \frac{{2^{\sqrt n } }}{{n!}}\left( {\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^n .
$$
Show that the left-hand side tends to infinity as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the really obvious reason as to why $\log k \leq \int_k^{k + 1} {\log tdt}$

Comment: Note that $$
\log k = \int_k^{k + 1} {\log kdt}  < \int_k^{k + 1} {\log tdt} 
$$ since the logarithm is increasing.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this a similar method to the derivation of Stirling's formula, but just a weaker approximation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation I guess you're technically not using "Stirling's formula" though.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for $n\ge 1$ the following inequlity holds:
$$
n^ne^{-n}\le n!\le n^{n+1}e^{-n+1}.
$$
You don't need Stirling's approximation here, this inequlaity can be proved by induction on $n$ (for the step the inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\le e\le \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ is required).

It follows that for all $n\ge 1$
$$
\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\ge\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^{n+1}e^{-n+1}}\frac{n^n}{e^n}=\frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{en}.
$$
Can you end now?

Comment: The righthand-side goes to $+\infty$ since $2^{\sqrt{n}}$ is “faster” than $n$. So it goes to $+\infty$ the lefthand-side too. Isn’t it?

Comment: Well, yes if you understand why $2^{\sqrt{n}}$ is growing faster than $n$.